# Why are there spaces between the images in my newsletter when it’s sent?

Tags: html, css, email, inline, newsletter

I have a newsletter to send, but some extra spaces appear between the rows in Yahoo, Gmail and MSN.

But this is what you see (funny that in jsfiddle it’s the same as Yahoo etc.) — notice the grey bars between the images:

- http://jsfiddle.net/FmyS5/

All borders are 0, all margins are 0. Do you see anything?

Tried with:

```
<table width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;">
```

but still the same.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem.  Do you mean between the rows of text on the image ( the "Porque mi camara..." ).  There is too much space between that text?  Or do you mean between the rows in the table?

Comment: well if you compare this image with the result in the jsfiddle you should be seing about 5 horizontal gray breaks wich should not be there :S yes?

Comment: Yeah, I totally answered my own question when I studied the JS fiddle output, but at first glance it looked the same :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding this:

```
img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

fixed the fiddle for me in Chrome 15. I couldn’t swear that this will apply to the various mail clients too, but it might work.

When I have to do HTML e-mails I use [Email on Acid](http://www.emailonacid.com/) to check the results in various mail clients. It’s worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try do add the following CSS to your Code

```
a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

And add to each a the height of the image inside. That should remove the gaps in the table.

Take a look at the jsfiddle (I only did the changes for the first row)

http://jsfiddle.net/FmyS5/9/

Comment: wow! that fixed it for jsfiddle and yahoo but not for gmail.. any idea why?

Comment: Take a look at this, maybe that will help you. http://www.nurulam.in/2010/06/email-newsletter-extra-table-row-gap-in-gmail/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to solve it;

```
a {
    float: left;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

...but it also causes some other damage to the footer.